# Jquery create animation swapping a series of images in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to create an effect where i display a short animation wherever the user clicks on a page. For this i need to quickly swap background image of a div with an array of image once. I couldn't find a way to do that just with the `animate()` or `fadeOut()` methods in jquery, so i tried it with `setTimeout()`, but all in vain. Please guide me to the best technique for what i am trying to do.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6j9p/)

P.S: I am having problems with including JSFiddle links in my posts, so i will leave it to others for edit. Although an explanation to this would help a lot.

Comment: Have you tried using an animated gif?

Comment: I do not want to go for animated gifs coz of the image quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
    var imgc;
var images = Array("http://s11.postimg.org/8iznatxr3/image.png",
               "http://s11.postimg.org/g08uq1na7/image.png",
               "http://s11.postimg.org/hgkd86q73/image.png",
               "http://s11.postimg.org/5fyx7gisf/image.png",
               "http://s11.postimg.org/3pfw5z19b/image.png");
$(document).click(function(e){

    imgc = -1;

    $('#ball').show().css({left:e.pageX +'px',top:e.pageY+'px'});

    setImage();


});

function setImage() {

    imgc++;

    var newimage = images[imgc];

    if (imgc < 5)  {
    $('#ball').fadeOut(50).css("background-image", "url("+newimage+")").fadeIn(50);

    setTimeout(setImage, 100);
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BT2wk/7/)

Note that I replaced `animate()` with `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`.

Comment: I was actually trying to create a fresh animation on every click. That is - each time the page is clicked, it should display 1-2-3-4-5 automatically in a sequence and then halt on 5.

Comment: @ishan I revised my answer and the JSFiddle. It is now working with animation.

Comment: Hi yani, thanks for the answer. It worked perfectly. Although i was wondering if you could help me a bit further by telling me which values to modify to stop flickering of images while they transit. I am trying to create an animation with several images in a sequence and right now there is a lot of flickering.

Comment: @ishan I can only point you to the right direction. You are getting the flickering because you are first fading off, and then fading in. So you have a dead zone in between. There are 3 things you can do - (1) add an internal div to 'ball' and set its image to the next image, then fadeout the first AT THE SAME TIME while fading in the 2nd. (2) write a cross jquery cross fade between 2 images

Comment: (3) use a 3rd party library that handles the CROSS FADE effect for you such as http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/simple-jquery-image-crossfade/. The benefits of this specific library is that it also cycles through several images, so you can load all 5 images and cycle through them on every click.